# Integration $1/x$ - complex number

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

Why there is no integral $$\int_{-e}^{e}\frac{1}{x}$$

And why integral 
 $$\int_{-e}^{-1}\frac{1}{x}= -1$$
and not
 $$\int_{-e}^{-1}\frac{1}{x}=(-1 + i\cdot\pi)$$

E.g. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration+1%2Fx+for+-e+to+-1

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Why do you expect the answer $-1 + i\pi$?

Comment: Exactly my tought? Why the need to use complex numbers? Oh I see now. You asked wolfram alpha and you got $log(-x)=log(x)+i\pi$ for $x>0$ right?

Comment: You can assign a value to $\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon} \frac{1}{x} dx$ via the Cauchy principle value but not via standard integration techniques as the singularity is badly-behaved.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Principal (adjective), not principle (noun).

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh thanks. Haha. I've been writing it wrong this whole time.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: You're not the only one. ;-) In my native language Swedish, those two words don't have the same pronunciation, and that probably makes it easier for me to tell them apart than for a native English speaker.

Comment: @HansLundmark Out of curiosity, how are they pronounced?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Well, that's not so easy to explain in writing, but the adjective "principal" is mostly used as a prefix in compound words ("principalvärde" = principal value), and the third syllable -al is long and stressed (with an "a" sound that doesn't exist in English), whereas the noun "principle" in Swedish is a two-syllable word "princip" (second syllable long and stressed). So the difference is quite huge, actually.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the indefinite integral of $\frac1x$ is $\ln|x|+C$, defined seperately on two domains, $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$.

1. The Riemann integral does not exist since
   $$\int_{-e}^e \frac1x\,dx=\int_{-e}^0 \frac1x\,dx+\int_0^e\frac1x\,dx=-\infty+\infty,$$
   which is not defined.
2. Simply:
   $$\int_{-e}^{-1} \frac1x\,dx=\ln|-1|-\ln|-e|=0-1=-1.$$
3. Why not $-1+i\pi$? First, real-valued function over real-valued range cannot give a complex integral, by the definition of the Riemann integral (it's a limit of real numbers, therefore either real, $\pm\infty$ or undefined). Second, remember that the indefinite integral of $\frac1x$ is not $\ln x+C$, that misses the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

You can write 
$$
\int_{-e}^e \frac{1}{x}dx = \int_{-e}^0 \frac{1}{x}dx+\int_{0}^e \frac{1}{x}dx
$$
and since $1/x$ is odd you get zero (you can change the variable in the first integral with $x=-y$. But to be really precise the singularity in zero is causing you headaches. This is by any means a formal answer. But I hope it can help understanding why is zero. If needed corrections are welcome.

Comment: No, it is not zero. Give me any extended real number, and using the definition I can "prove" that the value is this number. (Not that I'm willing to spend time on it. For an idea how to proceed, see [Riemann series theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).)

Comment: This is more or less a Cauchy principle value.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, $\int_{-e}^{-1}\frac{1}{x}dx=\log(-1)-\log(-e)=i\pi-(1+i\pi)=-1$

Comment: Since when the indefinite integral of a real function is a complex function, please?

Comment: @tohecz: It is when your arbitrarily chosen constant of integration happens to be complex.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: In the case of a *definite* integral, the constant of integration would cancel itself out, would it not ? Personally, I don't remember such constants ever being used outside the domain of indefinite integration, for precisely this reason.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's ridiculous, but you are probably right.

Comment: @Lucian: Yes, and it does cancel in the above calculation.

Answer (score 0):

For an integral to exist one needs at least one of the integrals $\int_{-e}^e \max(1/x,0) dx$ and $-\int_{-e}^e \min(1/x,0) dx$ to be finite.  If the first one is infinite and the second one finite then the integral equals $\infty$.  In the converse case it equals $-\infty$. If both are finite then you know what to do.